# Adding subdirectory after a directory using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I would like to redirect urls like:

domain.com/i/something-here  - into - domain.com/i/p/something-here

I though redirectMatch would do it, but its not keeping the last directory structure?

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/i/?$ /i/p/$1
```

Any ideas?

It has to play nice with another rewrite rule:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RedirectMatch 301 ^(/i)(/(?!p).*)$ $1/p$2
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /i/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /i/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^(/i)(/(?!p).*)$ $1/p$2
```

Comment: Ah, thats closer, thank you, but can it be possible to play nice with another rewrite rule?

See my edits in the question.